# How to write URL in windows media player 11 that was added to my Page C# ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

iam beginner in ASP.net and i was wrote this code to embed WMP11 to my page

```
<OBJECT ID="MediaPlayer"
  CLASSID="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" STANDBY="Loading
  Windows
  Media Player components..." TYPE="application/x-oleobject" VIEWASTEXT>
  <PARAM NAME="FileName" VALUE="file:///C:/diabfm.asx">
  <PARAM name="autostart" VALUE="`enter code here`false">
  <PARAM name="ShowControls" VALUE="true">
  <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">
  <PARAM name="ShowDisplay" VALUE="false">
  <EMBED TYPE="application/x-mplayer2" NAME="MediaPlayer">
  </EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```

and i want to know how to write URL to this

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how can you set the `FileName` form the server, then you can use a script tag as follows and reference a server-side member (MyURL).

```
<OBJECT ID="MediaPlayer" ... >
  ...
  <PARAM NAME="FileName" VALUE='<%= MyURL %>'>
  ...
</OBJECT>
```

Then in code behind.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string MyUrl
    {
        get; set;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyUrl = "http://foo/foo.mpg";
    }
 }
```